# Cant connect to azure websocket server with Unity3d Client

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, websocket

Im developing a small multiplayer game using unity3d engine (client side)
and i want to use websocket as a persistent connection to my game.

I've manage to create a websocket server using java and glashfish library and host it on azure and its working fine.

What im trying to do right now is to develop a Dot Net server with C#, hosted with a Web app and a Generic handler on Azure.
The problem is it cant connect and when i test it locally it shows me that it didn't receive ah websocket connection.

Im positive that on client side everything working good because it can connect to my Java server.
May it be a frame work issue? unity supports dot net 2.5

this is how it the code on the Generic handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)   
{   
   if (context.IsWebSocketRequest){}    
}
```

//context.IsWebSocketRequest => returns false

Will appreciate if you can help me sort this issue.